# Saving booleans fails in one environment with the message - General error: 1366 Incorrect integer value: ''

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp, mariadb, cakephp-4.x

The following works on my local environment:

```
$connection->update('requests', ['is_escalated' => false], ['id' => $serviceLineEntry->request_id]);
```

However, in my sandbox environment it fails with the following message:

```
[PDOException] SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1366 Incorrect integer value: '' for column 'is_escalated'
```

Local environment:

```
MariaDB (10.4.21-MariaDB)
PHP 7.4.25 (cli) (built: Oct 20 2021 09:30:08) ( ZTS Visual C++ 2017 x64 )
Copyright (c) The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.4.0, Copyright (c) Zend Technologies
```

Sandbox:

```
Azure Database for MySQL (5.7)
PHP 7.4.28 (cli) (built: Mar 24 2022 19:12:50) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.4.0, Copyright (c) Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v7.4.28, Copyright (c), by Zend Technologies
```

Is this due to the databases being different?

**Update 1**

Here's the column definition:

```
CREATE TABLE `requests` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    ...
  `is_escalated` tinyint(1) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
    ...
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=58249 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci
```

Comment: Suppose you are using something tinyint(1) instead of bool.

Comment: Can you show the table definition for both sandbox and local?

Comment: Added the definition. @markusZeller, correct, using tinyint(1)

Comment: Then you have to pass an integer: `['is_escalated' => 0]` or 1 for true.

Comment: Yes, it is the Database driver. PDO for example is very strict.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As your field is an integer, you can not pass boolean values.

```
['is_escalated' => 0] // false
['is_escalated' => 1] // true
```

You can cast a boolean to int

```
['is_escalated' => (int)true]  // 1
['is_escalated' => (int)false] // 0
```

Comment: Any explanations as to why I don't have to do this in my local compared to my other environments? PHP or MySQL/MariaDB issue?

Comment: It is the Database driver. PDO for example is very strict.

Comment: And, I should have used boolean as datatype then?

Comment: It depends on your preference. I do prefer unsigned tinyint(1), because anyways the database will store a byte - even on a boolean type (taking 1 bit, but stored as a byte).